# Laravel api не работает

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, api

Добрый день!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, не могу разобраться.

Ситуация такая: есть приложение на laravel.
Работает морда, при переходе на http://192.168.0.101/test/public вижу её.
Добавлен маршрут в api.
При переходе на http://192.168.0.101/test/public/index.php/api/v1/tests
получаю 404

Если запустить php artisan serve —host 0.0.0.0
то все работает на порту 8000:
и апи http://192.168.0.101:8000/api/v1/tests
и морда http://192.168.0.101:8000/

В чем косяк? Не могу найти как сделать, чтобы апи работало без php artisan serve —host 0.0.0.0

сервер nginx, php v7.0.25, сервер на виртуальной машине centos 7

Comment: А какие настройки сервера? Обычно нацеливают на /public согласно официальной документации.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov приложение ведет себя однообразно и при установке root в: /usr/share/nginx/html/test/public;

перепроверил, в конце не было слэша. Стало по-другому себя вести. "Дьявол в мелочах"

Comment: http://192.168.0.101/test/public/api/v1/tests  без index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nginx в директиве server:
root         /usr/share/nginx/html/test/public/;

Обязательно в конце указывать /